# java.sql.connection not showing up in netbeans

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public Connection MySqlConnection(){

        Connection conn=null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","root");
            return conn;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"MySql connection failed");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My Netbeans is not giving me options to import the `java.sql.connection`. I have added the `lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar` in my library. Additionally, I am also able to see all my databases in the services tab in Netbeans. I am working on a Swing project. Thank you!

Comment: Why should it?  It's a service of the IDE, you'd need to configure that directly via the IDE itself

Comment: This is the error I am getting,      Error: Unable to initialize main class javaproject.StudentsForm
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Connection

Comment: @funkybuddha Please don't update your question within the comments. Instead, 
click the "edit" link beneath the tags, and then update your question directly. You are more likely to get help with that approach, since not everyone goes through the comments.

Comment: You need to add `import java.sql.Connection;` at the top of your file (below the `package` statement)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I did but I wasn't able to still make the connection, instead of  the import java.sql.connection; I used java.sql.* and now i am able to connect! IS java.sql.connection deprecated or what?

Comment: No it isn't deprecated, but there is an important difference between `java.sql.Connection` and `java.sql.connection`: the first exists and the second doesn't. Class names in Java are case sensitive.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sorry for my typing mistake. I meant java.sql.connection. I wasn't able to import this but when I tried java.sql.*, i was able to make the connection.

Comment: Again, there is a difference between `import java.sql.connection` that you say you tried, and using `import java.sql.Connection` (note the lowercase `c` vs uppercase `C`). That last one will work.

Answer (score 1):

Put a string:

"requires java.sql;"

in the module-info.java file

[source](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/sql/the+package+java.sql+is+not+accessible)

Answer (score 0):

> Changes to the Connector/J API going from version 5.1 to 8.0:
>
> The name
>   of the class that implements java.sql.Driver in MySQL Connector/J has
>   changed from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. The
>   old class name has been deprecated.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html

Comment: Thank you . After changing my driver class I used import java.sql.* instead of import.java.sql.connnection and now I am able to connect to the database.